# incorrect backgroud image is displayed on 'ui-state-hover' for ui-icon-circle-close

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to extend jQuery-UI tabs element to display "Close" button. I would like the Close button to change the appearance on the hover event and remove the tab on the click. The code below almost works but the image displayed on hover even it incorrect. (I am using 'ui-icon-circle-close' which is correctly displayed as default, but on hover event it changes to a square which some partial image). Unfortunately - I can't post the screenshort - looks like for the lack of credit :-(.

I am using jQuery v1.8.2  and jQuery UI - v1.10.0

here is my entire javascript function

(I used Andrew Watts original version for jQuery 1.8 from repo http://github.com/andrewwatts/ui.tabs.closable and extended it to work for jQuery 1.9 with extra features.)

```
(function() {
$.widget( "ui.tabs", $.ui.tabs, {
options: {
    spinner: "<em>Loading&#8230;</em>",
    closable: false
},
_create: function() {
    this._super( "_create" );
    this._on({
    tabsbeforeload: function( event, ui ){
        if( !this.options.spinner ) {
        return;
        }
        var span = ui.tab.find( "span" ),
        html = span.html();
        span.html( this.options.spinner );
        ui.jqXHR.complete(function() {
        span.html( html );
        });
    }
    });
},

_removeTab: function( index ) {
    index = this._getIndex( index );
    var options = this.options;
    tab = this.tabs.eq( index ).remove(),
    panel = this._getPanelForTab( tab ).remove();

    if( tab.hasClass( "ui-tabs-active" ) && this.anchors.length > 2 ) {
    this._activate( index + ( index + 1 < this.anchors.length ? 1 : -1 ));
    }
},

_processTabs: function() {
    this._super( "_processTabs" );
    var self = this;
    var lis = this.tablist.children( ":has(a[href])" );

    if (this.options.closable === true) {
    var unclosable_lis = lis.filter(function() {
                return $('.ui-closable-tab', this).length === 0;
    });

    // append the close button and associated events
    unclosable_lis.each(function() {
                $(this)
        .append('<a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close ui-closable-tab"></span></a>')
        .find('a:last .ui-closable-tab')
                    .hover(
                        function() {
            $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
                            $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
                        },
                        function() {
                            $(this).css('cursor', 'default');
            $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
                        }
                    )
                    .click(function() {
                        var index = lis.index($(this).parent().parent());
                        if (index > -1) {
                            // remove this tab
                            self._removeTab(index);
                        }
                        // don't follow the link
                        return false;
                    })
        .end();
    });
    }
}
});

})(jQuery);
```

Any ideas how to make this code to display a correct hover icon?

Comment: couldn't make the icon transition work correctly with 'ui-state-hover' class so instead specified the icone explicitly: $(this).addClass('ui-icon-circle-triangle-e'); the full code for a closable tabs could be found here: https://github.com/RomanShestakov/ui.tabs.closable

Comment: https://rshestakov.wordpress.com/2013/04/13/how-to-make-closable-tabs-with-nitrogen-and-jquery-ui-1-9/